# How do I navigate from one content to another content in AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

To make my situation more clear, Im using jQuery - AJAX inside the main index.php to Load Content with No Page Refresh.

Here is my simplified Example, This is my main index.php page:

```
<!doctype html>

<div id="vis">
    <?php include( "./content/vis1.inc.php");?> //background part 1
</div>

<html>

<head>
    <title> Our website</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" /> // css style

</head>

<body>
    <ul id="nav">

        <li><a href="index">Home</a></li> // file in "Content" Folder
        <li><a href="about">About Us</a></li>// file in "Content" Folder
        <li><a href="contact">Contact</a></li> // file in "Content" Folder
    </ul>

    <div id="content">
        <div>
            <script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script> // file in "js" Folder
            <script src="js/general.js"></script> // file in "js" Folder
</body>

</html>

<div id="vis">
    <?php include( "./content/vis.inc.php");?> //background part 2
</div>
```

This is my general.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // initial
    $('#content').load('content/index.php');

    // handle menu clicks
    $('ul#nav li a').click(function() {

        var page = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#content').load('content/' + page + '.php');
        return false;
    });
});
```

So essentially all 3 pages are loaded up, and the it doesn't refresh when clicking between Index, About Us, and Contact links right? (which works fine)

However, I have an href link within the content of "content/index.php" (NOT the main index.php) so once I click on: e.g.

```
 '<a href="contact.php">Contact us</a>'
```

which is inside (content/index.php, the main index.php) It goes directly to the contact page without the Main Index.php file showing(which has the ajax and javascript script) So it's like I've just navigated directly to a php file normally.

How do I stop that from happening? I just want the this href link:

```
 '<a href="contact.php">Contact us</a>'
```

to "behave" the same way as the 3 links above in MAIN index.php (that has  Ajax, jquery scripts inside). Look at the directory below to make more sense. I read somewhere about window.location, but Im not sure what that is or what it does, my question may or may not be related to window.location, but just in case, I thought I'd bring it up.

It's really hard for me to find the right words for this Question, So I really do apologize.

This is the layout of my directory.
C:\Users\Hedi\Desktop\i-neo\htdocs\AJAX\

```
'index.php'     (main index php)
```

js (folder)

```
'general.js
 jquery-2.1.4.min.js'
```

content (folder)

```
'index.php
 contact.php
 about.php'
```

css (folder)

```
'styles.css'
```

Thank you.

Comment: Why not just make this a one page site and hide/show the different sections on click if you're going to load all the content for every page anyway?

Comment: Why do you have `<div id="vis">` outside the `<html>` tag?

Comment: well will it look the same for the user? and how would i go about navigating to another "hide/show" section when there is a redirection on the some content upon completing a form in a content?

Comment: Anyway, use this `$('ul#nav li a').click(function(e){ e.preventDefault(); ...the rest of your code` ...but doing this, when clicking on **home** you will load `index.php` in `index.php`.

Comment: @CliffBurton what's 'e' ?

Comment: You're not really using ajax (no `ajax`, no `post`, no `get`). You're just loading content.

Comment: @JeremyThille Well according to this video It's Ajax.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ytKc0QsVRY4

Comment: Yeah, okay. Technically it's asynchronous content load, ajax is more to fetch data (json etc.)

Comment: Look, regardless of what exactly it is. Im not looking for the exact definition of what AJAX is.

I just need to know how to do this.

And @CliffBurton that doesn't work, It just redirects me to that page without the Main index.php. Please Note, there is a difference between main index.php and the index.php found in the content folder.

Comment: @JeremyThille `load()` is a shortcut method for `$.ajax`...statement is inaccurate. It even supports data sent to server

Comment: Okay then, my bad. Sorry about that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delegate a click handler to the `#content` element that will use `load` for links that match that href pattern.

By delegating to the main content element you are accounting for future elements that will be loaded within it

```
$('#content').on('click', 'a[href*="content/"]', function(event){
     event.preventDefault();//prevent browser following the link
     var contentUrl = $(this).attr('href');
     $('#content').load(contentUrl );    
});
```

Selector used for target is : [Attribute Contains Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)

Comment: okay thanks, How do i show my coding in the comment section. It doesn't show it's original format

Comment: yes..this is specific to the links inside the content

Comment: Im getting a page not found error 404. Please note im fairly new to all this.

Comment: try changing to: `var contentUrl = this.href`

Comment: hit f12 and in network tab look at what url it is trying to connect to. See what the path difference is to where it would work in browser address bar opening that page

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
2http://localhost/ajax/style/style.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost/ajax/style/styles.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: this is all my code on general.js btw:


$(document).ready(function() {
 // initial
    $('#content').on('click', 'a[href*="content/"]', function(event){
     event.preventDefault();//prevent browser following the link
     var contentUrl = this.href;
     $('#content').load(contentUrl );    
});
});

Comment: that's only the error, and it's actually for a different file... look in network tab , can see every file that the page tries to use and it's path. Something is wrong in the path, but I can't tell what it is without seeing it. Need to fix your css file path also in `<link>` tag

Comment: Okay, I can see : ajax/  styles.css(red) style.css(red) ht5av.js
styles.css, jquery-2.1.4.min.js, general.js and favicon.ico. That's all i see in the network bar.  the main index file is not show the contents of those files anymore...

Comment: put this inside the code I gave you `alert('this new code is finding the content links')`. If the alert fires when you click one, you know we at least have the right search to find those links

Comment: okay, I put it after $('#content').load(contentUrl ); 
and nothing happens. just same 404 error when I click on links, btw you realize in my main index.php file, the link don't have .php at the end, thats what my previous general.js file was for... so my links in my main index are e.g.

<ul id="nav">
   
   <li><a href="index">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="about">About Us</a></li>
   <li><a href="contact">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>

Comment: need to see what link actually looks like in the content

Comment: you mean the names of the php files in the content folder? by links i meant the href links in the main index.php

Comment: Okay, im back, so what are you looking for exactly?